# Get database row from selected item in Combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, combobox

I have a Combobox which gets its data from my database.

```
var people = (from x in db.Person select new { Value = x.Id, Names = x.Namn + " " + x.EfterNamn }).ToList();
cbpeople.DataSource = people;
cbpeople.DisplayMember = "Names";
cbpeople.ValueMember = "Value";
cbpeople.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

And I have the SelectedIndex function

```
int id = cbpeople.SelectedIndex + 1;
string namn = (from x in db.Person where x.Id == id select x.Namn).ToString();
lblNamn.Text = namn;
```

So as you can see, I'm trying to have it select the information from the same row in the database and put them in labels. (The "cbpeople.SelectedIndex + 1;" is because I had no other way to get the ID from the SelectedValue).

But all it prints out is this long thing instead of the Name (on the label)

```
"SELECT \r\n    [Extent1].[Namn] AS [Namn]\r\n    FROM [dbo].[Person] AS [Extent1]\r\n    WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = @p__linq__0"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You calling ToString() over IQueryable object. Of course, it will return it's SQL representation. To execute query you can do this:

```
string namn = (from x in db.Person where x.Id == id select x.Namn).Single();
```